# Socket file transfer: Receiver stuck in reading from buffer/writing to storage

Tags: java, android, sockets, inputstream, file-transfer

```
static void sendFile(Socket socket, File file) throws IOException {

    File testFile = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/Camera/Test.jpg");
    byte [] buffer = new byte[(int)testFile.length()];
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(testFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Trying to read testFile from storage into buffer");
    bis.read(buffer,0,buffer.length); 
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Read testFile into buffer");
    OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Trying to write testFile from buffer into output stream");
    os.write(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Wrote testFile from buffer into output stream");
    os.flush();
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Outputstream flushed");
}

static void receiveFile(Socket socket) throws IOException {

    InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
    String receivedFileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Pictures/receivedFile.jpg";
    File receivedFile = new File(receivedFileDirectory);
    //check if directory exists, otherwise create it
    if (receivedFile.exists()) {
        Log.d(DebugTag, "Filename at destination already exists");
    } else if (!receivedFile.exists()) {
        Log.d(DebugTag, "Filename at destination does not exist, trying to create it!");
        receivedFile.createNewFile();
        Log.d(DebugTag, "Created file!");
    }

    Log.d(DebugTag, "Preparing file reception. Destination:"+receivedFileDirectory);
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(receivedFileDirectory);
    Log.d(DebugTag, "established outputstream to file directory");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
    int length;
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Trying to read inputstream into buffer and write file to destination");
    while ((length = is.read(buffer)) >0 ) {
        os.write(buffer,0,length);
    }
    Log.d(DebugTag, "File received.");
    os.flush();
    os.close();
    is.close();
    Log.d(DebugTag, "Closed in and out streams");

}
```

The sender file seems to work perfectly, I get every log message till "outputstream flushed".
On the receiver side, everything seems to go well until the code reaches the while loop: The last log msg I get is always "Trying to read inputstream into buffer and write file to destination", but not "File received" and the following messages. Weird thing is: I receive the test file and can open it (though it takes some seconds - don't know if this is typical for android).
**Any clues why the code gets stuck in the while loop?**

**Second question:** This is my first Android/Java app. Is this code alright for sending and receiving files over sockets? Even if files get bigger (up to >100MB)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `is.read(buffer)` will only return zero if the other side of the connection is gracefully closed (or throw an exception on errors), so what you are missing is the `socket.close()` on the sending side.

`os.flush()` is not enough here since TCP does not know when you are done sending data.